# what does the "?" and ":" sign mean in a line of java code?

Tags: javascript, processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a Question Mark “?” and Colon “:” Operator Used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-operator-used-for)
>   [Question mark in java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434021/question-mark-in-java-code)

I am writing codes for a RBG to HSV converter.
I have this line:

```
var d = (r==minRGB) ? g-b : ((b==minRGB) ? r-g : b-r);
```

i dont really understand what the "?" and the ":" means here.

Comment: `var d`? it's not java

Comment: Could it be you are talking about JavaScript?

Comment: its javascript. i am writing the rgb to hsv converter in java.

Comment: This one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/java-what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-within-the-parentheses-of-a-prin

Comment: @devilived javascript != java

Comment: @assylias yes. My question was not quite clear, my mistake. 
the line of code is from a javascript rgb to hsv converted, trying to write it in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `Ternary Operator`:

```
C = condition? A : B
```

is equivalent to

```
 if (condition){
  C=  A;
 } else{
   C=  B;
 }
```

It also support nesting i.e.  `C = condition1? A : condition2?D:E`, which is equivalent to

```
 if (condition1){
   C=  A;
 } else if (condition2){
   C=  D;
 } else{
   C= E;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the short way to make a condition :

```
  Condition ? Statment1 : Statement2;
```

Means

```
  If (Condition) {Statement1} else {Statement2}
```

Comment: how can this answer get upvotes? it's simply wrong. Terinary operators do not work for statements in java

Answer (score 2):

This is called ternary operator in java.

Based on  [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement (discussed in the Control Flow Statements section of this lesson). This operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses three operands.

If first expression results in true, then assign second operand as value, otherwise third operand as value.

Comment: @Quoi: Question heading said java, that is why this answer. If question is on javascript, I am sorry!

Comment: Ok. I was confused `var` +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

It means

```
if (r==minRGB)
  d = g-b
else
  if(b==minRGB)
     d=r-g
  else
    d=b-r
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called **`ternary operator` (?:)**: -

```
System.out.println(condition? value1 : value2);
```

The above expression is evaluated like: -

```
if (condition) {
    System.out.println(value1); 
} else {
    System.out.println(value2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c-based languages, it means:
    ?  :

Its short-hand for an if-else, basically.

Answer (score 0):

it work similar to if than else

```
if (r==minRGB)
    d = g-b;
}else{
    if  (b==minRGB)
    {
        d = r-g;
    }else{
        d = b-r;
    }
}
```