# Came across this in code I'm working on

Tags: java

Came across this line in a program I'm cleaning up:

```
 isFound = !isFound ? isFoundOnPost : isFound;
```

I tried to Google this, yieleded no results. I know this is not the best question but could someone explain what this is doing? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-operator-used-for

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera that is not really a duplicate

Comment: I do not see how this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @assylias yes. But answer is there. `This question already has an answer here:`

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera The duplicate flag is for duplicate questions, not duplicate answers - see for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85725/why-do-people-use-similar-answers-as-justification-for-closing-questions-as-dupl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called as [Ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) operator. It is same as

```
if(!isFound) {
   isFound = isFoundOnPost;
} else {
  isFound = isFound; //No need, Just to make clear for you.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, I had never seen this style of code before!

Answer (score 0):

This is use of ternary operator
its syntax is

```
variable=(condition)?IfConditiontrueThisExecutes:IfConditionFalseThisExecutes;
```

it is somewhat similar to if-else ,
whenver the condition before `?` evaluates to true the statement after `?` gets executed otherwise statement after `:` get executed and variable on LHS is assigned that value based on which statement executed