# Could someone explain this bit of code to me (simple)

Tags: java

I have these two methods. I understand the "getTotalSalary" one but don't really get the way in which "getAverageSalary" is written. I don't understand why the question mark and colon is used as well as the "(size() != 0)" and 0 at the end.

This is the coding:

```
public double getTotalSalary() {
    double total = 0;
    for (Employee e : empReg) {
        total = total + e.getSalary();
    }
    return total;
}

public double getAverageSalary() {      
    return (size() != 0) ? this.getTotalSalary() / this.size() : 0;
}
```

empReg is the name of the ArrayList. Employee is a class which consists of "name" and "salary". getSalary is obviously a method returning the salary.

Comment: I believe what's confusing you is the `Ternary Operator` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java

Comment: The getAverageSalary() implementation is all about avoiding division by zero. It's Java's ternary operator, described here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 6):

The question mark is called the ternary operator, and it is used to make a decision based on an evaluation. It is often used to replace if statements, since they do the same thing. For example, an if statement with that would be written:

```
if (size != 0)
    return this.getTotalSalary() / this.size();
else
    return 0;
```

In my experience, I only use it if I want to reduce the code size. However, it does make the code a bit more difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot divide by zero.
? and : is a ternary operator. It means that if the expression before `?` is true, then `this.getTotalSalary() / this.size()`will be returned, otherwise return 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's called ternary operator in java, here you have some examples: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion: [What is a Question Mark "?" and Colon ":" Operator Used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-operator-used-for)

It explains

> A traditional if-else construct in C, Java and JavaScript is written:

```
if (a > b) {
    result = x;
} else {
    result = y;
}
```

> This can be rewritten as the following statement:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```