# Evaluating "IF ELSE" shorthand as part of a toString() Implementation

Tags: java, oop

I have write the following toString() methode

```
public String toString() {
    return "Product: "+ this.productName + ", Barcode: " + this.barCode
            + ", Expiration Date: " + this.expirationDate.toString() + ", Customer Price: "
            + this.customerPrice + ", Shops Price: " + this.shopsPrice
            + ", Instore Amount: " + this.inStoreAmount + ", Sale: "
            + (this.sale == null) ? "Not on sale" : + this.sale.toString();
}
```

But there is a problem with the way I use the if statement.

```
eclipse: "cannot covert from string to boolean"
```

Comment: what is the problem? Post the error message please

Comment: It looks like you have a potential double `+` going on if the condition is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an issue with the balancing of concatenation operator `+`. Also, I edited your method to be the following:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Product: "+ this.productName + ", Barcode: " + this.barCode
            + ", Expiration Date: " + this.expirationDate.toString() + ", Customer Price: "
            + this.customerPrice + ", Shops Price: " + this.shopsPrice
            + ", Instore Amount: " + this.inStoreAmount + ", Sale: "+ ((this.sale == null) ? "Not on sale" : this.sale.toString());
}
```

When you are writing IF-ELSE short hand, try to keep everything in a `(...)` set of parentheses to keep track of things easily. I don't care what other professionals say about this, but if this helps you to understand things, so be it!

Answer (score 1):

This is illegal syntax

```
(this.sale == null) ? "Not on sale" : + this.sale.toString()
```

and a compilation error should have alerted you to this problem.

Instead, use

```
((this.sale == null) ? "Not on sale" : this.sale.toString())
```

I've placed the entire [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-operator-used-for/10336927#10336927) into parentheses to be clear.