# BST: How to find the successor key given a key?

Tags: java, parent-child, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm using a BST. Given a key, how will I find the successor key? This is the code I have so far. I've managed to insert a new key and retrieve a value given the key. Now, I need to finish the next method. How would I approach this?

```
class BST<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements RangeMap<K,V> {
class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node parent;
    KVPair<K,V> kv;
    K key;
    V value;
    public Node(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        parent = left = right = sentinel;
    }
}

private Node root;


public void add(K key, V value) {
    // TODO: Implement me(basic score)
    root = add (root, key, value);
}

private Node add(Node x, K key, V value){
    if (x == null){
        return new Node(key, value); }
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if (cmp < 0){
            x.left = add(x.left, key, value);}
            else if (cmp > 0 ){
                x.right = add(x.right, key, value);}
                else if (cmp == 0){
                    x.value = value;} 
    return x;
}


public V get(K key) {
    Node x = root;
    while (x != null){
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if (cmp < 0){
            x = x.left;}
            else if (cmp > 0 ){
                x = x.right;}
               else if (cmp == 0){
                   return x.value;}
      }
    return null;
}


public K next(K key) {
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You would need a private method to getNode of key
2. Then you get successor of that node and return its value
3. You should also update your "V get(K key)" method to use the getNode(K Key) method to avoid code duplication

I've written all 3 methods below

```
    private Node getNode(K key) {
        Node x = root;
        while (x != null){
            int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
            if (cmp < 0){
                x = x.left;
            } else if (cmp > 0 ) {
                x = x.right;
            } else if (cmp == 0){
                return x;
            }
          }
        return null;
    }

    public K next(K key) {
        Node x = getNode(key);
        if (x.right != null) {
            x = x.right;
            while (x.left != null) {
                x = x.left;
            }
            return x.key;
        }
        Node p = x.parent;
        while (p != null && p.right == x) {
            p = p.parent;
            x = x.parent;
        }
        return p.key;
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        Node x = getNode(key);
        return x==null?null:x.value;
    }
```

Comment: this is a stupid question, but it says it cannot find the symbol parent. Would I add that in my Node constructor? if so, how? so far, I have public Node(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;

Comment: what is the "it" that says it cannot find parent. Where in the code is this occurring. The method next() is a part of your BST class right ?... and the inner class Node has a parent field defined ... so the next() method should be able to access the parent field

Comment: ah yes that's my problem I don't have the parent field defined, but I'm not quite sure how

Comment: do I simply just add "Node parent;" in the constructor class?

Comment: class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        Node parent;
        KVPair<K,V> kv;
        K key;
        V value;
        public Node(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

Comment: also what does "return x==null?null:x.value;" mean in the get method?

Comment: Questions mark operator - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-operator-used-for

Comment: your node class looks fine - can you show me the line of code where you get the error message -- and also the exact wording of the error

Comment: I am no longer getting the error message! Is the last get method necessary for the entire next method to work?

Comment: you had a get method already which is similar in code to my getNode method ... since it is not a good idea to have duplicate code - i basically rewrote your get method to use the getNode method that I wrote. So this last get method is a replacement for the get method you have already

Comment: I have to keep the get method though:( with the same parameters

Comment: If you mean you have to keep the signature of the get method the same, then the signature is the same for the one you have and the one I wrote

Comment: If you mean you have to keep the implementation of the get method the same , then sure you can keep the original one and remove the one I wrote. Things will still work correctly but you'll have code duplication like I mentioned before

Comment: wait but yours returns a Node and mine returns the V

Comment: you get method and my get method both return V ... my getNode method return a Node

Comment: hey, if this answer solved your problem, accept it please