# How do I interpret this line of Java code?

Tags: java

So this looks like a fancy way of using an if statement to check if `bom.getCharsetName()` actually returns a valid character set name. However, it is quite confusing and I've never seen this syntax before. How does this break down piece by piece?

```
String charsetName = bom == null ? defaultEncoding : bom.getCharsetName();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Question Mark "?" and Colon ":" Operator Used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336899/what-is-a-question-mark-and-colon-operator-used-for)

Comment: Just Java's version of a ternary condition.

Comment: If bom is null, use defaultEncoding, if not, use `bom.getCharsetName()` for `charsetName`'s value

Comment: Those duplicates are not satisfactory IMO, because they don't explain the return value of an assignment as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And why does this matter? There´s no assignment in neither of the two operands. Only the return-value of the ternary operator is assigned, which is a pretty normal assigment, nothing special about this.